# Can TEC1-12706 be damaged by running on low current?

Tags: peltier

I'm using a HDD power supply of 12V 2A. The plate stopped heating or getting cold. I tested the power supply which is working fine. Tried changing the power supply by mobile charger with no effect. I do not have 12V 5A power supply available to know for sure.

Comment: How do you control the current?

Comment: Im not controlling the current. The power supply is rated at 12V & 2A max current.

Comment: Exactly. So how did you "run on low current"?

Comment: Well, the specification says 12V 5A which is around 60W. I'm using a lower than specified current of 2A.

Comment: My point is that you only control the voltage and you are either hitting the OCP of the power supply or not, but the chance of your power supply having a 2 A _constant current_ limit is slim to none. Load is also not constant but depends on temperature difference and a few other factors. Measure the voltage and current under load and report back.